# In i3, how do I focus the top-level window container?

Tags: i3

I often find myself wanting to move the entire content of one workspace into another.  My current method is to—

1. spam my hotkey for `focus parent` until I **think** I've selected the top-level container, then
2. press my hotkey for `move container to workspace $NUM`.

However, I often underestimate how nested my layout is, and didn't press `focus parent` enough times, so I end up moving only part of the windows.  It's frustrating.

How can I be sure I've selected the top-level container?

---

To be clear, I don't want *only* to be able to move the whole content of a workspace into another, but to get the full generality of running arbitrary commands with the top-level container selected.

Comment: seems like the kind of thing a specialty ipc script would be good for.  see [i3ipc-py](https://github.com/acrisci/i3ipc-python) and its example scripts.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's an elegant solution for this problem. As a workaround you could simply repeat the `focus parent` command before moving the container to make sure you have the top-level container focused. E.g. something like

```
bindsym $mod+t focus parent, focus parent, focus parent, focus parent
```

Depending on how nested your layouts get, you might want to repeat it some more to be reasonably sure you have selected the top-level container.

Answer (score -1):

If I understand correctly, I think you are asking the wrong question. You should not move everything to another workspace, but rename your workspace. You can define a hotkey for this, e.g.

```
bindsym $alt+s exec i3-input -F 'rename workspace to "%s"' -P 'Destination: '
```

I realize now that this works only if your other workspace is empty. Is that the case?

Comment: This is very helpful, but doesn't answer the question fully. The target workspace isn't necessarily empty.

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear. I'll edit the question to clarify.

Comment: @Anko No, I think you were clear from the beginning, I just didn't connect all the dots. In this case I cannot help you, I'm afraid!